# Log4Net appender filter for specific exception type?

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to filter my appender based on the type of exception being logged.  Is this possible in log4net?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

log4net does not support this directly. You can however quite easily implement your own filter by deriving either from the `IFilter` interface or the `FilterSkeleton` class (both in `log4net.Filter` namespace).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public class ExceptionTypeFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
     override public FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
     { 
          var ex = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject as YourExceptionType;
          return (ex != null) ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;         
     }
}
```

This filter you can then use like a regular filter. For further reference you may look at the source code of the standard log4net filters.

Comment: This code would only log your specific exception type. If you wanted to filter out a specific exception, you could reverse the Accept & Deny. FilterDecision.Accept means log it. Deny means don't log it. Probably obvious, but took me a minute to think through. :)

Comment: And if you have more than one filter, you might need to use FilterDecision.Neutral.